# Background image of a Word file doesn't resize when document is

Tags: microsoft-word, images

I want to add a background image to a Word document. I'm creating a letterhead and need to drop in an image that was created in Illustrator.

I tried adding it as a background image in Word, but when I resize (or zoom) the Word document, the background isn't resizing along with it.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

What you possibly want is in effect a watermark.

Go to View Header & Footer and insert it there

or other methods for [Word 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HP051896401033.aspx), [Word 2002 & 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/285055) or [Word 2000](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/211324) (you don't mention which version you are using)

Answer (score 0):

The Word background image feature is not intended for use in printed documents; rather, it is intended for use in creating web pages with Word (not something I recommend, incidentally.) If you want to have an image in the background, the best solution is probably to insert the image as an image, and use a text box for your text. This will give you more of a "page layout" environment.

Comment: im using word 2010 beta
and i dont want the background to be washed out

Comment: there is no reason it should be washed out if added as an image, unless you put an object in front of it which is not 100% transparent (ie text box should have no fill colour at all). Personally I would prefer to put the image in the header with no text wrapping so it appears behind the whole page and appears on every page, which is essentially what a watermark does (as per other answer). This will appear "washed out" on screen to make it easier to edit text in front of it, but not when printed or converted to other formats eg pdf